# Check validation for numbers only

Tags: javascript, jquery

following is my piece of code which checks if the input format is EMAIL which comes from the form input or not and validates accordingly i want to know how can i modify the following code that validates if the input was only number

```
  if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
                var error = true;
                $('#email_error').fadeIn(500);
            }else{
                $('#email_error').fadeOut(500);
            }
```

Comment: THANKS TO ALL FOR SUCH A QUICK RESPONSE!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
if(isNaN(email*1)){
    //evaluated to NaN
}else{
    //evaluated to number
}
```

In this case the `(email*1)` have the possibility to evaluate to `NaN`, and thus will fail the check because the list of falsish values are `0,"",false,null,undefined,NaN`

Comment: No typos here. Very nice. Couldn't you also do `if(+email)`? Minor note/random thought: Huh, there are generally quite a few ways to check if a value is a number in JS.

Comment: You can't compare to `null`, so technically it's not a falsy value.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville `null*1` evaluates to `NaN` and fail the `if()` check

Comment: Ah, you weren't clear on that before the edit. Now I see what you did there. =)

Comment: It looks like the most elegant solution, but if I have to choose between `if(email*1){ //evaluate to number` - which relies on side-effects and needs a comment and `$.isNumeric(email)` which does not, I would lean towards the isNumeric one...

Comment: sorry for the downvote, but: var email = "0"; email*1?'you are right':'you are wrong';

Comment: @valentinas: Ah, right, that makes sense because 0 is a `falsy` value.

Comment: @FaizanQadri I seriously suggest you to use Elliot Bonneville's answer. Don't rely on side effects. See my comment above for an example how in edge-cases it all goes wrong, when isNaN(Number()) is very reliable. Write a wrapper function if you don't like the function inside function look.

Comment: @ajax333221 As I mentioned above - don't rely on side-effects. Use isNaN(Number(email)) or you will be .... var email = "0.0"; (email=="0"||(email*1))?'right':'wrong'

Comment: @valentinas that happens with `isNaN(Number(email))` too :(

Comment: @ajax333221 No, it doesn't: var email = "0.0"; (!isNaN(Number(email)))?'number':'NaN'

Comment: @valentinas `("0.0"*1)===0`, it is exactly the same `Number()` and `(x*1)` bye

Comment: Genious! this was what i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's IsNumeric method.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

```
$.isNumeric("-10");  // true
```

Comment: Good answer, but the OP doesn't need jQuery for this.

Comment: I know. Still, it's an extra function call when you could just go native.

Comment: I would normally agree with Elliot, but since jQuery is already used, isNumeric is close to native ;) I do not like to mix native methods, since you get horrible stuff like `$(this).jqMethod({ this.nativeMethod()})`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (email.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
   //it's all numbers
}
```

**EDIT**
As mentioned in the comments, to ensure that the entry is ALL numbers, the regex would have to include the begin and end characters, `^` and `$`:

```
if (email.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
   //it's all numbers
}
```

Or even more succinctly:

```
if (email.match(/^\d+$/)) {
   //it's all numbers
}
```

I don't deserve the credit for that fix, but I did want to correct it for anyone who may come find this later.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville I didn't proof it.  Am I wrong?  I'll delete if so.

Comment: No, it's right. Just... there are simpler methods of doing this. =) I generally like to avoid RegEx unless I really need it.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville Hmm... this one seems pretty simple to me, but I'm genuinely interested in why you think it's not.  Is it inefficient?

Comment: I don't have any sources that say it's less efficient than `isNan(Number(myStr));`, but I have a hunch using RegEx will be slower. Plus, I'm biased against RegEx, so that factored into my comment as well.

Comment: Understood. I'm happy to take note (and get better) when I do things wrong. But thanks for not down voting a correct answer!

Comment: Oh yeah, lets get some RegEx into the native/jQuery mix ;)

Comment: Why use `[0-9]` when you can use `\d`? Also this would say true `email = "asdf0123456789";` It needs `^` and `$`.

Comment: @epascarello—because `0-9` may be seen as clearer, it's only one more character to type so no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Check if converting the email address to a Number object returns a 'Not a Number' value; if not, the input was a number. The code would look like this:

```
if(!isNaN(Number(email)) {
```

Comment: Whoops, yep, typos will be the death of me. Nice catch.

Comment: @El indeed, you now wrote `isNan` :)

Comment: So the person I tend to agree with managed to create a monster of a native test to see if some text is a number or not. Please tell me what construct would not work if you did just isNaN instead of isNaN(Number(email))

Comment: @mplungjan: Not sure if this is an issue but see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6441835/339852

Comment: It ain't an issue in my browsers (osx Safari5 Chrome 18, Fx 12): http://jsfiddle.net/MWwBq/